# Doublind nodes linked list

Tags: c

I need to double every node in a linked list, the doubled nodes should be right after the copied node.
The function got the list.beg as parameter.

```
while (p != NULL)
{
    q = p;
    q->next= p->next;
    p->next= q;
    p = q->next;    
}
```

For some reason the loop never ends.

Comment: It is unproductive to comment on incomplete code snippets. Please provide a [complete minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And what does "double every node" mean? Does it mean double the `number` or make a new copy of the node? If it is the latter you need to actually `malloc` new nodes and not just fiddle with the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You are *just* doing `q = p;`, so you're creating a node that links back to itself. That is, what you're doing is equivalent to:

```
p->next = p;
```

You have to *allocate* a new node for `q`.

It's a little difficult to be sure *without* the `struct` definition, but, here's some refactored code:

```
while (p != NULL) {
    q = malloc(sizeof(*q));

    // NOTE: this only works if the node does _not_ have a pointer to some data
    // otherwise, a "deep copy" is required
    *q = *p;

    p->next = q;
    p = q->next;

    printf("%i\n", q->data.number);
}
```

---

When I mentioned "deep copy" above, it would apply if the node had an element such as:

```
const char *str;
```

Where `str` was created initially via (e.g.):

```
p->str = strdup(buf);
```

possibly as part of an `fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);` loop.

Then, in the duplication code, after the `*q = *p;`, we'd need:

```
q->str = strdup(p->str);
```

Comment: Sorry.. should have given more details.. Heres the whole function:

    void dupList (struct tDesc *lst) {
    struct tNo *p, *q;
    p = lst->beg;
    
    q = (struct tNo *)malloc(sizeof(struct tNo));
    
    while(p != NULL)
    {     
   *q = *p;
   q->next= p->next;
   p->next= q;
   p = q->next;
 }
}
Those are my structs: 
    struct tStud {
  int num;
};
struct tNo {;
  struct tAluno dado;
  struct tNo *next;
};
struct tDescritor {
  int qtd;
  struct tNo *beg;
};
obs: sorry if code is not properly entered.. never used stackoverflow before.